# Why is ...permission.C2D_MESSAGE added to my app?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, permissions

My permissions are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

but according to Google Play developer console, when I upload my apk, the following permissions are required by my app...

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.android.vending.BILLING
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
com.myapp.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Why are wake lock, and messaging added to my app by default? Is it because I've added facebook activity/support for sharing/liking?

This did not happen when I first used Eclipse, but now that I moved it to Android Stuido it occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be documented but when you add firebase to an app, these permissions are automatically added to your app:

see https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/4kobvm/admob_firebase_and_extra_permissions/